# Parsing JSON with Alamofire Problems

Tags: ios, json, parsing, dictionary, swift3

I am new to swift and in programming, and I am trying to parse a JSON with the help of Alamofire and SwiftyJSON, if the JSON file is simple, I have no problems and working good, but when I have something like Dictionary -> Dictionary -> Array -> Dictionary, problems begin, so I have the following code:

```
func performCYesterdayWeatherFetch(forSelectedCity: String)
{
    let properString = forSelectedCity.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
    Alamofire.request("http://api.apixu.com/v1/history.json?key=MY_KEY&q=\(properString!)&dt=2016-10-20").responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        guard response.result.isSuccess else
        {
            print("Error while fetching remote rooms: \(response.result.error)")
            return
        }

        guard let json = response.result.value as? JSON,
        let forecastJson = json["forecast"].dictionary else
        {
            print("YESTERDAY PROBLEM")
            return
        }
        for item in (forecastJson["forecastday"]?.arrayValue)!
        {
          let day = item["day"].dictionaryObject
           guard let yesterdayTempCels = day?["avgtemp_c"] as! Double?,
            let yesterdayTempFahr = day?["avgtemp_f"] as! Double? else
          {
            return

          }
```

MY_KEY - is really my key, the problem is not in that i didn't input the key.

It always get in else here:

```
guard let json = response.result.value as? JSON,
        let forecastJson = json["forecast"].dictionary else
        {
            print("YESTERDAY PROBLEM")
            return
        }
```

They result JSON looks like that: 
The thin I need is avgtemp_c and avgtemp_f

[image: JSON PIC]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you get that type `JSON`?

Comment: I saw that in  a tutorial, and from request I get a JSON file, in other example (where is 1 array it works)...

Comment: But that must be a library (maybe you're using `SwiftyJSON`) as JSON is not a type inside `Alamofire` neither `iOS API's`

Comment: I am using SwiftyJSON, forgot to write, I will Edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a solution where you don't even need `SwiftyJSON` to get those values.

```
let properString = forSelectedCity.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
Alamofire.request("http://api.apixu.com/v1/history.json?key=MY_KEY&q=\(properString!)&dt=2016-10-20").responseJSON { (response) -> Void
    guard let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any],
        let forecastDictionary = json["forecast"] as? [String: Any],
        let forecastDayArray = forecastDictionary["forecastday"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
            print("YESTERDAY PROBLEM")
            return
    }

    for item in forecastDayArray {
        guard let day = item["day"] as? [String: Any],
            let yesterdayTempCels = day["avgtemp_c"] as? Double,
            let yesterdayTempFahr = day["avgtemp_f"] as? Double else {
                return
        }

        // Here you should have the values that you need
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow Thank you so Much! Worked like a Charm)))